# Pass object and attribute at once for reflect-metadata in TypeScript like in C#

Tags: c#, typescript, reflection, reflect-metadata, typescript-decorator

In C# we've DataAnnotation to add meta attributes on properties. I need this functionality in TypeScript for a ldap model class. Decorators should set the LDAP attribute which is internally used in the LDAP directory

```
export class LdapUser {
    @ldapAttribute('sn')
    sureName: string;
}

export function ldapAttribute(attributeName: string): (target: any, propertyKey: string) => void {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        Reflect.defineMetadata("ldapAttribute", attributeName, target, propertyKey);
    }
}
```

But to fetch the `ldapAttribute`decorator value I need to pass object and attribute name as raw strings like this:

```
let user = new LdapUser();
let sureNameAttribute = Reflect.getMetadata("ldapAttribute", user, "sureName"); // sn
```

It works, but that seems bad practice, since it would result in a runtime instead of compiler error when `sureName`attribute is renamed in `LdapUser`without applying this to the `Reflect.getMetadata()`call. And also intellisense is missing. So I'm searching for a solution like this:

```
let sureNameAttribute = Reflect.getMetadata("ldapAttribute", user.sureName);
```

Problem here is that I need some sort of reflection to divide `user.SureName`in the attribute name (here `sureName`) and class object (here `user`). I already did something like this in C# using reflection, but have no clue how to do this in TS.

### Workaround

It's not as good as it would be using Reflection in C#, but better than only use plain strings:

```
export function getLdapAttribute<T>(instance: T, attributeName: keyof T) : string {
    let value : string = Reflect.getMetadata("ldapAttribute", instance, attributeName);
    return value;
}
```

usage

```
let attributeValue = getLdapAttribute(user, "sureName"); // cn
```

Sadly we have no intellisense here. But at least we get an compiler error if the attribute name doesnt exist.

Comment: And the question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use next approach to solve this problem:

```
export type FieldSpec<TModel, TResult> = ((model?: TModel) => TResult) | string;

export function getFieldName<TModel, TResult>(fieldSpec: FieldSpec<TModel, TResult>): string {
    if (typeof (fieldSpec) == "string" || !fieldSpec) {
        return fieldSpec as string;
    } else {
        var fullFunc = fieldSpec.toString();
        var parts = fullFunc.split(/[.;}]/).filter(x => x.trim().length > 0);
        return parts[parts.length - 1].trim();
    }
}
```

With these helpers you can write:

```
export function getLdapAttribute<T>(instance: T, attributeName: FieldSpec<T,any>) : string {
    let value : string = Reflect.getMetadata("ldapAttribute", instance, getFieldName(attributeName));
    return value;
}

let user = new LdapUser();
let sureNameAttribute = getLdapAttribute(user, () => user.sureName);
```